# How to download a image to a drawable folder from a url?

Tags: android, url, imageview, drawable

I would like to add a image to a xml image view, and needs to be updated on timely basis.Whether is there a possibilty of updating directly to the drawables or how to do it from device memory i.e. downloading & calling from internal memory to the xml imageview.Kindly help me with an example or a snippet.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all I was pretty much sure I could do it from sd card,as matter of fact I had curiosty whether we could update the drawables folder.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. You will have to save image either to the SD CARD or the
data/data/package folder. You can not write/save image in drawable/res. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update drawable folder.Only thing you can do is save the image in sdcard or in application memory ie /data/data//image.png.To set the image dynamically you can get reference of your image in your activity using findviewbyid and then set its image wherever required.

Answer (score 1):

Research a bit before you ask a question...

During runtime you do not have access to your projects folders, as they are compiled to .apk file and that file runs on the device, now how on earth can you modify those folders while your app is running?

Try downloading it to your SD card or internal memory instead...